# Crosstab function for table is not carrying the values along

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

My current sae_table(id, cbid, description, value) looks like in the picture.

I want to pivot it, so it can look like this:

```
id     cbid    month    day   year    test   actual_value   normal_ran   no
1    60051     09       27    2016  "Urinary" "some vegetans"
2    60051     09       30    2016  "Chest"   
3    60052  ....
```

I have tryied doing the crosstab using id,description and value, but all the values only displays under the Month column.

```
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB('SELECT id, description,value from sae_test')
 AS ct ("id" integer,  "Month" character varying(4000),"Day" character varying(4000),"Year" character varying (4000),
 "Test" character varying(4000),"Actual Value" character varying(4000),"Normal Range" character varying(4000),"No Test option" character varying(4000));
```

Above crosstab result (values don't distribute accross columns properly):

```
id    Month    Day   Year     ...
1      09                     ...
2      27                     ...
3      2016                   ...
```

I also tried pivoting just using the cbid, description and value. But it only displays distinctive cbids. And in this case one cbid can have multiple rows.

```
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB('SELECT * from sae_rel_data2()')
 AS ct ("CBID" character varying(4000), "Month" character varying(4000),"Day" character varying(4000),"Year" character varying (4000),
 "Test" character varying(4000),"Actual Value" character varying(4000),"Normal Range" character varying(4000),"No Test" character varying(4000));
```

The result for the query above was (eliminating second entry for the same cbid, when those entries should have been kept):

```
cbid    month   day    year   ...
60051    09     27     2016   ...
60052                         ...
60053    09     27     2016   ...
60029                         ...
```

[image]

**UPDATED:**

What if I have ordinal numbers that helps identify nth records for a CBID? Can I then create a loop function that will do the crosstab for a cbid in each ordinal level, and then combine each with a UNION or JOIN statement? Would that work? if so, how can that loop be created? I am not familiar with it.

Example:

```
event_crf_id;        description,            value,        ordinal
444;                 "CBID";                "60051";          1
444;                 "Month";               "09";             1
444;                  "Day";                "27";             1
444;                  "Year";               "2016";           1
444;                  "Test";         "Urinary tract US";     1
444;               "Actual Value";   "some vegetans lesions"; 1
444;                 "Normal Range";         "";              1
444;               "No tests option";        "";              1
444;                 "Month";                "09";            2
444;                 "Day";                  "30";            2
444;                 "Year";                "2016";           2
444;                 "Test";             "Chest/abdomen CT";  2
444;             "Actual Value";         "3 bladder lesions"; 2
444;              "Normal Range";              "";            2
444;             "No tests option";            "";            2
```

Something like:

```
count=count (distinct ordinal) from sae_test()
for each event_crf_id in (select * from sae_test() where ordinal=count)
   SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB('SELECT event_crf_id, description, value from sae_test()) 
 JOIN ...
count=count+1
```

Is there such a possibility? how can this join be performed? or does postgres automatically knows that while in a loop the new entries will continue to be added to table? (sorry, I am really new to Postgres and databases in general)

Comment: Your data is ambiguous. What value should be presented for row `60051` and column `Day`? Should it be `27` or `30`? (Btw, deliver your data as text, no images).

Comment: There should be a unique value to determine which date or test or 'actual value'  is part of the 2. 3. or nth 60051? second question: how do you separate each 60051 row groups if these values inserted in an unsorted way?

Comment: Just think this way, the number 60051 represents a patient, and that patient can have multiple labs in different dates. That's why you see the 60051 repeatedly. So one cbid can have multiple entries, but each entry has a unique id. But why is that when I do the SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB('SELECT id, description,value from sae_test'), all the data is displayed under just the second column?

Comment: Because crosstab fırst colum needs rows which have same unique values. your id is a sequantial number so it cant be sorted. but if you use cbid, it will also eliminate its second third nth entries because he doesnt know which date or other colums is the part of nth cbid.

Comment: If you want get the rows for patient 60051 just from 27th day of the month, how it looks like your query?

Comment: I kind see what you are saying. I am updating the question with another example. Please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I literally had to do this the hard, immature way. But it did provide me with the results I wanted. How can I do this in a more sophisticated, efficient way?

```
Select a.event_crf_id, rel_test_CBID, a.row_number, a.rel_test_name, rel_test_actual_value, rel_test_month, rel_test_day, rel_test_year, rel_test_normal_range From (Select id.event_crf_id, id.ordinal as row_number, id.value as rel_test_name
from item i, item_data id 
where i.item_id=id.item_ID and id.item_id IN (2185,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268) and i.description = 'Test') as a

left join (Select id.event_crf_id, id.ordinal as row_number, id.value as rel_test_actual_value
from item i, item_data id 
where i.item_id=id.item_ID and id.item_id IN (2185,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268) and i.description = 'Actual Value') as b
on a.event_crf_id = b.event_crf_id and a.row_number = b.row_number

left join (Select id.event_crf_id, id.ordinal as row_number, id.value as rel_test_month
from item i, item_data id 
where i.item_id=id.item_ID and id.item_id IN (2185,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268) and i.description = 'Month') as c
on a.event_crf_id = c.event_crf_id and a.row_number = c.row_number

left join (Select id.event_crf_id, id.ordinal as row_number, id.value as rel_test_day
from item i, item_data id 
where i.item_id=id.item_ID and id.item_id IN (2185,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268) and i.description = 'Day') as d
on a.event_crf_id = d.event_crf_id and a.row_number = d.row_number

left join (Select id.event_crf_id, id.ordinal as row_number, id.value as rel_test_year
from item i, item_data id 
where i.item_id=id.item_ID and id.item_id IN (2185,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268) and i.description = 'Year') as e
on a.event_crf_id = e.event_crf_id and a.row_number = e.row_number

left join (Select id.event_crf_id, id.ordinal as row_number, id.value as rel_test_normal_range
from item i, item_data id 
where i.item_id=id.item_ID and id.item_id IN (2185,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268) and i.description = 'Normal Range') as f
on a.event_crf_id = f.event_crf_id and a.row_number = f.row_number

left join (Select id.event_crf_id, id.ordinal as row_number, id.value as rel_test_CBID
from item i, item_data id 
where i.item_id=id.item_ID and id.item_id IN (2185,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268) and id.ordinal = 1 and i.description = 'CBID') as g
on a.event_crf_id = g.event_crf_id

order by a.event_crf_id, a.row_number asc;
```

Comment: put your example data [hier](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) with `insert into from your_table` from both table.